# "Your windows license will expire soon" Popping up every couple of minutes

Tags: windows-10, licensing

This dialog has popped up more than 20 times since I booted up my computer. Before, it would show itself once, then go away.
[image: Windows License Expire]

When I go to settings there's nothing unusual, and it doesn't show me that my license will expire soon. What do I do to get rid of this notifacation?

Things I've looked in so far to get rid of this dialog:

- Some people told me to delete LicensingUI.exe which is what this dialog is, but I feel like that would break something.
- Rearming my license does not work and the message continues to show up, even if there's no license key installed.

Comment: What happens when you search that phrase on-line? Do any solutions pop-up (besides the licensingUI deletion)? If solutions come up, could you indicate why they're not working for you?

Comment: What i've found is that I'm supposed to rearm my license key, which I actually did, but its still showing up.

Comment: That's useful information. Can you [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1562920/edit) your question to explain what steps you've taken so far and what the result of those steps is? This would really help people answering as then they won't suggest you something you've already tried.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! What else did you find so far on your search for a solution? When I search this issue on Google I find multiple links. Some mention rearming (what you've tried already it seems), some mention something about a group policy setting. Can you look through the results, try out the solutions and edit your question to include what didn't work and why (did it give an error, did it crash, etc...)

Comment: Check Task Scheduler, if there's a task for it, it'll keep re-warning you at whatever interval it's set to run

Comment: What license type is it? OEM, Retail, Enterprise?

Comment: The message indicating the license will expire does not tell the entire story.  I suspect this is a trial installation or a machine that normally would normally be connected to a KMS.  "What do I do to get rid of this notification?" - We cannot answer this question without additional information about your system.  Are you using volume license?

Comment: I have the exact same issue all in the sudden. I really don't know what to do...